# How should i mention the licence of my code?

Tags: discussion, licensing

When posting code to be reviewed (for instance code that already has been pushed on a github repo), how should I mention the licence of the code ?

I definately can't put the licence notice in the code snippet as it is enormous.

Is the following a correct way of stating this fact ?

> Please note that as stated on github this code is GPLV3 : LINK

This statement looks pompous to me, but this is an important matter anyway

Comment: By posting your code on Stack Exchange, you are sublicensing it (the content of your post) under CC-BY-SA as stated in the terms of service and in the footer of every page on the network. Mentioning the license your github repository is using is superfluous and, in the end, useless.